# Expose stored procedure using oData service

Tags: stored-procedures, odata, eclipselink, olingo

I need to expose my `stored procedure` using `oData`. I have done it using `EclipseLink JPA` but without `odata`. Any link to the tutorial or an example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to expose a stored procedure, will be to create a corresponding `FunctionImport` for it.

You can create a `complex type`, that corresponds to the return structure of your procedure, and map the input variables of the procedure to the `FunctionImport` input parameters.

Note: OData 4 defines something similar called ActionsImports too. The the only difference is, that ActionImports are "side effecting"

If you are using OData 4 and your procedure is changing some data you should use an `ActionImport` else, if its just reading the data and returning some results use `FunctionImport`.

If you are using OData 2 and you have a side effecting procedure, You should use a Function Import with `IsSideEffecting` flag set to true;

Links to implementation documents

- [Olingo 2: Adding Function Imports to OData Services with the JPA Processor](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/tutorials/jpafunctionimport.html)
- [Olingo 4: How to build an OData Service with Olingo V4
  Part 6: Action Imports and Function Imports](https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/action/tutorial_action.html)